# ¿Cómo compilar varios .scss en un solo archivo .css? Gulp y nodejs

Tags: nodejs, gulp, scss, gulp-sass

Tengo un archivo principal estilos.scss (y varios **.scss** más) y me gustaría que este se compilara a estilos.css.

El problema es que al compilar se crean varios archivos de tipo .css (como ven en la imagen).

Los demás archivos de tipo .scss los llamo a través del archivo principal (**estilos.scss**) con el siguiente código.

```
@import "rejilla_pura";
@import "recursos_generales";
```

Cuando compila, veo que el archivo estilos.css incluye los elementos importados, pero a la vez me crea varios archivos ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta agregar un guión bajo antes del nombre, por ejemplo `_rejilla_pura.scss` a los que no quieres que se cree un archivo .css. El @import lo seguirás haciendo como lo has estado haciendo `@import "rejilla_pura"`

Comment: Si funcionó, le cambié la extensión a los archivos y compiló en uno sólo. Gracias.

Comment: Te lo pondré como respuesta por si le sirve a alguien mas ;)

Comment: Por cierto te sugiero que termines el [tour] del sitio para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla

Answer (score 2):

Lo que tu necesitas en Sass es llamado *Partials* o Parciales, de la [documentación](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials):

> Si tienes un archivo SCSS o Sass que quieres importar pero no quieres que se compile en un archivo CSS, puedes agregar un guión bajo al incio del nombre del archivo. Esto le dirá a Sass que no lo compile en un archivo CSS normal. Luego puedes importar estos archivos sin usar el guión bajo.

En tu caso nombraremos a tus archivos `_rejilla_pura.scss` y `_recursos_generales.scss` y los importamos de la siguiente forma:

```
@import "rejilla_pura"
@import "recursos_generales"
```